# Is it possible to pass js variable to template file

Tags: javascript

I have select drop down created in functions.php and in js file getting onchange value of drop down. I want to know do I pass this variable to my template file?? This is my code in functions.php file

```
?><select id="land_unit" name="unit_name" ><?php
$result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from unit");
                 foreach($result as $row) {
                  $unit_id=$row->unit_id;
                  $unit_name=$row->unit_name;     
                 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $unit_id; ?>" <?php if($land_unit== $unit_id){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $unit_name; ?></option>
<?php  } ?></select><?php
```

This is my code in js file where i am getting correct alert

```
$("#land_unit").on('change', function()
{
 var unit_id=$(this).val();
//alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Pass a value from a jQuery script to a rendered page has nothing to do with WordPress. Have a look to jQuery docs, expecially [DOM manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Answer (score 0):

Put you JS and PFP code in same file and try. Try to use some hidden fields in template file to set any value from JS, using the ID or name of the hidden field.